# Time Posting Data Analysis

Tags: correlation

I work in a professional services company and would like to get some analytics on how discipline the fee earners post their times to the system may have an impact to the revenue.

One area that I am thinking of is to see if there is a correlation between how late the time entry is posted after the work was done and whether that time entry is being written off (i.e. does not make it to the bill to the client).

Is this a reasonable thing to analyse?
If so, what technique should I be looking at to analyse this, e.g. correlation, regression, clustering, etc?

If there are other things that I can analyse as well, please let me know.

I am quite new to this data analytics/mining/science so please guide me. I have some understanding of R language which will be my primary language in analysing the data (and SQL to get the data).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you visualize the lateness of time posting over the revenue, you will see the clear picture and understand the correlation.

What you need is to create the corresponding columns in your tables.

Comment: Thanks. What visualzation is appropriate for this kind of analysis?

Comment: Start with a simple scatter plot, x=lateness, y=revenue.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to answer the question "what is the relationship between the lateness of time posting and the probability of the time will get written off", what technique should I use? Is it Binomial Distribution or something else?